# I need to find all the sharepoints sharedlinks with the ms graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I need to find through the ms graph api all sharepoint shared links given to a specific "User". Any idea how I can  do this. If it's not possible I would be ok to use the "Site" objet as a starting point.

My general understanding is that I should do follow this path  like

User->Drive->DriveItems

and then check if the "share" attribute is not null but I'm unable to build a valid MS graph API

Any input would be appreciated thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found it:

GET /users/{id | userPrincipalName}/insights/shared

ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/insights-list-shared?view=graph-rest-1.0